# How can one calculate the Nth non-holiday from a given date?

Tags: c#, list

Let's say I have a `List<DateTime> L` that contains holidays dates in the US. Let `DateTime d` be today 2017/10/19. I want to calculate the next n-th non-holiday date (where `n` is a positive integer let's say) consecutive to `d`.

To do this, a concept of "iteration over all dates `>= d` except dates belonging to `L`" is involved. What is the best c# design to handle this ? (Performance is quite important.)

*Remarks* :

1. at each non-holiday date in the "iteration" process, I will use the current non-holiday date to perform a calculation with it
2. `n` could be like 40-50 times "365"
3. the set of holidays dates is finite indeed, I don't use holiday calendars defined with generation rules
4. I am also interested in created the list of "iterated" non-holidays days until the "`d+n`", or the list of non-holidays dates between two dates

Comment: how does this connect with your title "Iterating over values excel certain values"?

Comment: except ; correcting right now

Comment: "Performance is important" is meaningless; correctness is also important, as is maintainability, robustness, legibility, localizability, and a thousand other things. If you have reason to believe that *the cost of computing a date* is going to make the difference between success and failure of your project then say what your performance budget is, what you've tried already, and how it failed to meet your empirical performance standards.

Comment: @EricLippert You see, "Performance is quite important" was not a sentence alone. It was : "What is the best c# design to handle this ? (Performance is quite important.)" This means : "what is the best c# design to this that could also take care of performance." And "best c# design" includes correctness, maintainability, robustness, legibility, localizability, and a thousand other things. Thx.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj: "That could also take care of performance" is still ambiguous though. Typically, simplicity of code and optimization are in tension. Just *how* efficient do you need this to be? If you need an approach which won't perform any heap allocations at all, for example, that might be significantly more complex - hurting the legibility etc. I've provided what I believe to be "reasonably efficient" approaches, but whether they're *efficient enough* is a different matter.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj: Assuming you're only interested in (say) the next 100 years, it would be *really pretty quick* to generate a list of all non-holiday dates for the next 100 years and then use that for the rest of your app. It would take a certain amount of memory, of course...

Comment: Jon is right. Another way to look at it is: if you can't tell me what your performance budget is, then *performance is not actually important to you yet*. If it was important, you'd know something empirical about your budget.

Comment: To Jon and Eric : honestly, the functionality will only take `DateTime`s and `List`'s thereof as parameter and will be so low level in the library that I don't give a flying monkey about anything else than performance. So my budget is : the fastest method among all methods. These types of iterations will be done few hundreds of time (for different non-holidays lists, `DateTime`'s, `n`'s) in a whole calculation that should take less than roughly 10e-5s.

Comment: Ah, so you need the absolutely fastest possible option? Sounds like you should design your own custom hardware then. Presumably the reaction is "No, it doesn't need *that* level of optimization" - so there's a finite level of optimization required. You also need to consider different kinds of performance - do you have enough *memory* budget that you can precompute all the non-holiday days for the next 50 years and put sufficient indexes in to let you get at appropriate starting points (e.g. one per month) easily?

Answer (score 4):

### If the set of holidays is finite (and *reasonably* small)

It's really easy to create an infinite sequence of dates:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime start)
{
    DateTime current = start;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `Except` with your holidays to get an infinite stream of dates except your holidays:

```
var nonHolidays = GetDates(DateTime.Today).Except(holidays);
```

To get the nth value (starting with 0 as the first) you can use `ElementAt`:

```
var specificWorkDay = nonHolidays.ElementAt(n);
```

Of course if you're doing this a lot, you might want to generate "all the first X non-holiday dates" which is easy too:

```
var multipleWorkDays = nonHolidays.Take(x).ToList();
```

Note that even though `GetDates` looks like it's in an infinite loop, that just means it will keep iterating forever *if you keep asking the returned iterator for data* (and until you hit `DateTime.MaxValue` of course). It will only iterate as far as you ask it to. Just don't call `GetDates().ToList()` or `nonHolidays.ToList()`!

### With a potentially-infinite sequence of holidays

Suppose you have an `IEnumerable<DateTime> GetHolidays(DateTime start)` method which returns a sequence of holidays *in order*, potentially infinite, from the given start date. (It's very important that the sequence is in order, as otherwise we can't tell reliably whether or not a date is a holiday.)

At that point, you need to be slightly smarter, as `Except` is not going to work. It's still possible to do efficiently though:

```
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetNonHolidays(DateTime start)
{
    var holidays = GetHolidays(start);
    var current = start;
    foreach (var holiday in holidays)
    {
        // Yield everything until the next holiday
        while (current < holiday)
        {
            yield return current;
            current = current.AddDays(1);
        }
        // Skip this holiday, then look for the next one
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
    // No more holidays? Now we can just yield infinitely...
    while (true)
    {
        yield return current;
        current = current.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the set of holidays is also infinite? There's one Christmas a year forever. Now, the OP says that the set of holidays is in a list, and so it is finite. But what if someone took your advice and also made an infinite lazy list of holidays?

Comment: @EricLippert: Agreed, with a non-list set of holidays, a different approach is required. Will edit to indicate this.

Comment: @EricLippert: Have added a solution for iterating over the infinite approach. Untested, but I *think* it's okay - would value your feedback, as ever.

Answer (score 1):

We can accomplish your goal using some helper functions *(not required if one already has a list of holidays to pull from)*:

```
static DateTime NthWeekDay(DateTime value, int n, DayOfWeek weekday) {
    return value.AddDays(-(((int)value.DayOfWeek) % 7) + (((int)weekday) % 7) + (7 * n));
}
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GenerateHolidays(DateTime value) {
    yield return new DateTime(value.Year, 1, 1); // New Year's Day
    yield return NthWeekDay(new DateTime(value.Year, 1, 6), 2, DayOfWeek.Monday); // Martin Luther King Jr. Day
    yield return NthWeekDay(new DateTime(value.Year, 2, 6), 2, DayOfWeek.Monday); // Presidents' Day
    yield return NthWeekDay(new DateTime(value.Year, 5, 31), 0, DayOfWeek.Monday); // Memorial Day
    yield return new DateTime(value.Year, 7, 4); // Independence Day
    yield return NthWeekDay(new DateTime(value.Year, 9, 6), 0, DayOfWeek.Monday); // Labor Day
    yield return NthWeekDay(new DateTime(value.Year, 10, 6), 1, DayOfWeek.Monday); // Columbus Day
    yield return new DateTime(value.Year, 11, 11); // Veterans' Day
    yield return NthWeekDay(new DateTime(value.Year, 11, 3), 3, DayOfWeek.Thursday); // Thanksgiving Day
    yield return new DateTime(value.Year, 12, 25); // Christmas Day
}
static IEnumerable<DateTime> GenerateHolidays(DateTime x, DateTime y) {
    var anchor = ((x < y) ? x : y);
    var diff = Math.Abs((x - y).Days);

    foreach (var year in Enumerable.Range(0, (diff + 1)).Select(i => (new DateTime((anchor.Year + i), 1, 1)))) {
        foreach (var holiday in GenerateHolidays(year)) {
            yield return holiday;
        }
    }
}
```

And then do something like the following:

```
var n = 137;
var begin = DateTime.Today;
var end = begin.AddDays(n);
var dates = Enumerable
    .Range(0, (end - begin).Days)
    .Select(a => begin.AddDays(a))
    .Except(GenerateHolidays(begin, end)); // or use your own IEnumerable<DateTime> of holidays here
```

`dates` will be an enumerable that should contain all dates between `begin` and `end` that are not a holiday.

Comment: Hehe, the completionist in me wanted to do **far** more but figured [the US Federal Holiday list](https://www.opm.gov/policy-data-oversight/pay-leave/pay-administration/fact-sheets/holidays-work-schedules-and-pay) would be more practical. You now have me researching if that's even possible...